# Serve generated static files in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services

I have a [SailsJS](https://sailsjs.com/) app which I'm trying to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk by following Amazon's [NodeJS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html).

My website comes up, but all the requests for static files (css, js, images) are being responded to with 404's.

There's apparently two ways to go about this, which are:

### 1. Serve the files using SailsJS

`npm start`, which is my command to start the server, serves these files locally using [Express' static middleware](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/assets#?static-middleware) and this works beautifully on my machine. On the server, these requests appear in nginx' access log, but they don't reach my NodeJS app. Where are these going?

### 2. Serve the files using the nginx proxy server

By default `npm start` (or `sails lift`) runs whatever script necessary to move the static files from `assets` into `.tmp/public`, which is where they should be served from. To serve these files with nginx according to the tutorial I need to add them to the `.ebextensions/staticfiles.config` file, which now looks like:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:staticfiles:
    /dependencies: /.tmp/public/dependencies
    /docs: /.tmp/public/docs
    /images: /.tmp/public/images
    /js: /.tmp/public/js
    /min: /.tmp/public/min
    /favicon.ico: /.tmp/public/favicon.ico
```

I've tried:

- moving the static files from `.tmp/public` to `static` because I thought the hidden folder `.tmp` was somehow unreachable by nginx
- checking in the `static` folder, which works, but adding it to the `.gitignore` and deleting it seems to cause this to not work.

It really *seems* like nginx ignores files that were made after the NodeJS start command was run. How can I serve my automatically generated static files?